# curl example to pycurl

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

Here is my command

```
curl -i -H 'X-Storage-User:12345:12345' -H 'X-Storage-Pass:new1234' https://ssproxy.ucloudbiz.olleh.com/auth/v1.0
```

Result

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 05:49:06 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 126
Connection: close
X-Auth-Token-Expires: 51114
X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkdfefef8dfsfsefsf
X-Storage-Token: AUTH_tkdfefef8dfsfsefsf
X-Storage-Url: https://ssproxy.ucloudbiz.olleh.com/v1/AUTH_3xxsdff_sdfwef_sdfwf
X-Trans-Id: tx76sdsefwfwwt
```

How do I convert it to pycurl?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normally, curl's `--libcurl` option is a great first step for this sort of question as it shows the underlying libcurl options used.

Comment: @DanielStenberg um.... 
May I use the requests module?
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Comment: Of course you can and that's a more "pythonish" approach - although that isn't really an answer to this question but isntead a pycurl alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrisponding command in pycurl written in Python 3:

```
import pycurl
import sys

def bodycb(buf):
    import sys
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(buf)

def headercb(buf):
    import sys
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(buf)

headers = ['X-Storage-User:12345:12345', 'X-Storage-Pass:new1234']

pycurl_connect = pycurl.Curl()
pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://ssproxy.ucloudbiz.olleh.com/auth/v1.0')
pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, bodycb)
pycurl_connect.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, headercb)
pycurl_connect.perform()
```

You need to pass in your headers in a list using pycurl.HTTPHEADER. The headercb and bodycb functions are just callbacks to print the responses headers and body to the console.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance :)